# 2 images in one div,with slider in middle

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display 2 images on a div. They will initially be separated by a handle line with 2 arrows. When user drags the handle line left, the left image will catch more space, related to the user drag. The same for the image on the right. I am following the example of this website image--> [website]: http://california-t.ferrari.com/en/#overview

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="sketch">
    </div>
      <div class="sketch-wrapper">
                                    <div class="before-after sketch-container" style="height: 270px;">
                                        <img class="sketch-before" alt="sketch basis" src="Untitled.jpg" style="clip: rect(0px, 380px, 270px, 0px;"></img>
                                        <img class="sketch-after" alt="sketch finished" src="sketch2T.jpg" style=";"></img>
                                      <div class="sketch-overlay">
                                            <div class="sketch-before-label"></div>
                                            <div class="sketch-after-label"></div>
                                      </div>
                                        <div class="sketch-handle" style="left: 380px;">
                                            <span class="sketch-left-arrow"></span>
                                            <span class="sketch-right-arrow"></span>
                                        </div> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>


   </div>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
.content {

    width: 900px;

    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top:0px;





}

.sketch{
    width:inherit;
    height: 1200px;
    background-image: url(backSketch4.jpg);
    margin-top: 70px;

}

.sketch-wrapper{
    height: 270;
    width: 760px;
    display:block;
    margin-top: -1025px;
    margin-left:70px;

}
.sketch-container{
    display:block;
    -mox-box-sizing: content-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: content-box;
    -o-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
}
.sketch-before, .sketch-after {
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    display: block;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px;    
}
.sketch-before{
    z-index: 20;
}
.sketch-after{
    z-index: 10;    
}

.sketch-overlay, .sketch-before-label, .sketch-after-label {
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.sketch-overlay, .sketch-before-label, .sketch-after-label {
    position: absolute;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
.sketch-before-label, .sketch-after-label{
    transition-property: opacity;   
}
.sketch-before-label:before, .sketch-after-label:before {
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -19%;
    line-height: 38px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.sketch-before-label:before, .sketch-after-label:before {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;  
}
.sketch-handle {
    height: 38px;
    width: 38px;
    position: absolute;

    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -22px;
    margin-top: -22px;
    border: 3px solid #0F0;
    border-radius: 1000px;
    -moz-border-radius: 1000px;

    -webkit-border-radius:1000px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);

    z-index: 40;    
}
.sketch-handle:after {
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: 22px;
    box-shadow: 0px -3px 0px #FFF, 0px 0px 12px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);  
}
.sketch-handle:before {
    bottom: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 22px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px #FFF, 0px 0px 12px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
}
.sketch-handle:before, .sketch-handle:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 3px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #FFF;

    height: 9999px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -1.5px;
    z-index: 30;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
}
.sketch-left-arrow {

    border-right: 6px solid #F00;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -17px;
    box-sizing:content-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
}
.sketch-right-arrow {
    border-left: 6px solid #F00;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: -17px;
    box-sizing:content-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
}
.sketch-left-arrow, .sketch-right-arrow {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border: 6px inset transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -6px;   
}
```

the result I have so far is this, the slider is not moving an the second image is not visible from the center to right...I think something is wrong with the css...
http://imageshack.com/a/img855/517/i7wf.jpg

Comment: The `img` tag is self closing, you don't need `</img>`

Comment: I changed it, but does not work again... probably something is wrong with css display:block or something else related to it

Comment: To make the 2nd image visible from the center to the right you need a closing bracket on the clip property on the first image i.e. clip: rect(0px, 380px, 270px, 0px);

Comment: A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be nice, when you want some help, try to make the least amount of work possible for the people helping you

Comment: oops I didnt know about jsFiddle...I am newbie, thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt.
It may need some fine tuning.

http://jsfiddle.net/7Geh2/2/

See the jsfiddle for the rest of the code

```
<div>
    <img id="img-1" src="http://california-t.ferrari.com/en/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2014/01/149m_overview_slide_blue.jpg"/>
    <img id="img-2" src="http://california-t.ferrari.com/en/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2014/01/149m_overview_slide_red.jpg"/>
    <div id="handle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The mouse button never 'unclicks' in the div. So you click once instead of dragging

Comment: answer updated with another new version. Happy with this one :)

Comment: At first I did not thought that Javascript should be needed to implement this...!!I thought css would be enough...But I would like to thank so much for the code provided